# How to read the value in the first cell in a selected row of a Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which contains data from two different tables called ITEMS and ORDER_ITEMS. 
The datagrid's format is like this - 
**Item ID | Item Name | Unit Price | Quantity | Amount**

Here, the columns ItemID, ItemName, Price belong to the table ITEMS and the columns Quantity and Amount (amount = price*quantity) belong to the table ORDER_ITEMS.

So I am having some problem with creating the selected row as a new object (or instance) of ITEMS type to catch the ItemID. How can I read the ItemID attribute of the 'selected' row?

---

Update:
When I tried use the following code (as per the syntax given by John K.), I got the error - *Error  1   'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
     string id = selectedItemsGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

I found some info about the problem. Just found in the Microsoft Library that it is in the namespace System.Windows.Forms.dll. But I'm using Windows Presentation Foundation now. Do you think it's related to the problem I'm currently facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DataGrid.CurrentItem property.  That give you the object that is data bound to the current row.  So for example:

```
class DataClass {
   string ID { get; set; }
   ...
}

...

DataClass current = (DataClass)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
string id = current.ID;
```

Comment: Oh, yes, that will give the object bound to the current row. But it is giving me the error. The problem is, the rows are the combinations of multiple objects (in my case, it's 2). So I'm not being able to instantiate an instance of either type using the row values.

Comment: By the way, I'm now getting this error - *Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2[Business.ITEM,Business.ORDER_ITEM]' to type 'Business.ITEM'.*

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem you can't cast to an anonymous type.  You could 1) Use reflection  2) If you are in .Net 4, cast to dynamic or 3) create a data class rather than using an anonymous type

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try the third one. It seems to be the easiest one, since I don't have time to learn reflection and I can't run VS 2010 on my Dell Mini 10v. *I'll tell post the result here shortly.* :) Again, thank you very much for the cool idea. :-)

Comment: THIS WORKED: Added two more attributes to the dataclass ORDER_ITEMS. It's from your answer. Thanks a million for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ItemId is in the first (0) column of the datagrid... The Selected rows will return an array so if only 1 row is selected the first (0) element would contain the row...

Try:

```
string  strVal =  DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it. But I cannot see SelectedRows in the IntelliSense. If I type it by myself, Visual Studio is giving an error reading 

*'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

PS: I've tried to do SelectedRow also. It didn't work either.

Comment: Looks like that answer is for a DataGridView, which is a WinForms control, not the WPF DataGrid that you are using.