# Selecting a full row in DataGrid, Silverlight Navigation Application

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

This might be a stupid question but i haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

I am trying to make it possible when a user clicks on a certain row in the datagrid the entire row will be selected.

In WPF i just have to set the selection mode to FullRowSelect but in my current project the datagrid doesnt have this option. The only 2 options i have now are SelectionMode : Single or Extended.

Currently my XAML code looks like this :

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="ShowKlant" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False"        CanUserReorderColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="ShowKlant_SelectionChanged" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF4568C7" RowBackground="#AA73A4D4">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Klant ID" Binding="{Binding KlantID}"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Voornaam" Binding="{Binding Voornaam}"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Achternaam" Binding="{Binding Achternaam}"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

The reason i want to do this is that when the entire row is selected i can hopefully use code similar to this to get the value from the first cell.

```
idklant = Convert.ToInt32(ShowKlant.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

Found the solution thanks to this question, after using my error report in a search.

link to solution:
[How to read the value in the first cell in a selected row of a Datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843578/how-to-read-the-value-in-the-first-cell-in-a-selected-row-of-a-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the selection mode of the data grid?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="test" SelectionMode="Single" >
```